# Extract overlapping and non-overlapping time periods using R (data.table)

Tags: r, date, time, data.table, overlap

I have a dataset containing time periods during which an intervention is happening. We have two types of interventions. I have the start and end date of each intervention. I would now like to extract the time (in days) when there is no overlap between the two types and how much overlap there is.

Here's an example dataset:

```
data <- data.table( id = seq(1,21),
                    type = as.character(c(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1)),
                    start_dt = as.Date(c("2015-01-09", "2015-04-14", "2015-06-19", "2015-10-30", "2016-03-01", "2016-05-24", 
                                         "2016-08-03", "2017-08-18", "2017-08-18", "2018-02-01", "2018-05-07", "2018-08-09", 
                                         "2019-01-31", "2019-03-22", "2019-05-16", "2019-11-04", "2019-11-04", "2020-02-06",
                                         "2020-05-28", "2020-08-25", "2020-12-14")),
                    end_dt   = as.Date(c("2017-07-24", "2015-05-04", "2015-08-27", "2015-11-19", "2016-03-21", "2016-06-09", 
                                         "2017-07-18", "2019-02-21", "2018-01-23", "2018-04-25", "2018-07-29", "2019-01-15", 
                                         "2019-04-24", "2019-09-13", "2019-10-13", "2020-12-23", "2020-01-26", "2020-04-29", 
                                         "2020-08-19", "2020-11-16", "2021-03-07")))

> data
    id type   start_dt     end_dt
 1:  1    1 2015-01-09 2017-07-24
 2:  2    2 2015-04-14 2015-05-04
 3:  3    2 2015-06-19 2015-08-27
 4:  4    2 2015-10-30 2015-11-19
 5:  5    2 2016-03-01 2016-03-21
 6:  6    2 2016-05-24 2016-06-09
 7:  7    2 2016-08-03 2017-07-18
 8:  8    2 2017-08-18 2019-02-21
 9:  9    1 2017-08-18 2018-01-23
10: 10    1 2018-02-01 2018-04-25
11: 11    1 2018-05-07 2018-07-29
12: 12    1 2018-08-09 2019-01-15
13: 13    1 2019-01-31 2019-04-24
14: 14    2 2019-03-22 2019-09-13
15: 15    1 2019-05-16 2019-10-13
16: 16    2 2019-11-04 2020-12-23
17: 17    1 2019-11-04 2020-01-26
18: 18    1 2020-02-06 2020-04-29
19: 19    1 2020-05-28 2020-08-19
20: 20    1 2020-08-25 2020-11-16
21: 21    1 2020-12-14 2021-03-07
```

Here's a plot of the data for a better view of what I want to know:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = start_dt, xend = end_dt, y = id, yend = id, color = type)) +  
  geom_segment(size = 2) +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: overlapping time periods]

I'll describe the first part of the example: we have an intervention of type 1 from `2015-01-09` until `2017-07-24`. From `2015-04-14` however, also intervention type 2 is happening. This means that we only have "pure" type 1 from `2015-01-09` to `2015-04-13`, which is 95 days.
Then we have an overlapping period from `2015-04-14` to `2015-05-04`, which is 21 days. Then we again have a period with only type 1 from `2015-05-05` to `2015-06-18`, which is 45 days. In total, we now have had (95 + 45 =) 140 days of "pure" type 1 and 21 days of overlap. Then we continue like this for the entire time period.

I would like to know the total time (in days) of "pure" type 1, "pure" type 2 and overlap.

Alternatively, if also possible, I would like to organise the data such, that I get all the seperate time periods extracted, meaning that the data would look something like this (type 3 = overlap):

```
> data_adjusted
    id type   start_dt     end_dt
 1:  1    1 2015-01-09 2015-04-14
 2:  2    3 2015-04-15 2015-05-04
 3:  3    1 2015-05-05 2015-06-18
 4:  4    3 2015-06-19 2015-08-27
 ........
```

The time in days spent in each intervention type can then easily be calculated from `data_adjuted`.

I have similar answers using `dplyr` or just marking overlapping time periods, but I have not found an answer to my specific case.
Is there an efficient way to calculate this using `data.table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method does a small explosion of looking at all dates in the range, so it may not scale very well if your data gets large.

```r
library(data.table)
  alldates <- data.table(date = seq(min(data$start_dt), max(data$end_dt), by = "day"))
  data[alldates, on = .(start_dt <= date, end_dt >= date)] %>%
    .[, .N, by = .(start_dt, type) ] %>%
    .[ !is.na(type), ] %>%
    dcast(start_dt ~ type, value.var = "N") %>%
    .[, r := do.call(rleid, .SD), .SDcols = setdiff(colnames(.), "start_dt") ] %>%
    .[, .(type = fcase(is.na(`1`[1]), "2", is.na(`2`[1]), "1", TRUE, "3"),
          start_dt = min(start_dt), end_dt = max(start_dt)), by = r ]
#         r   type   start_dt     end_dt
#     <int> <char>     <Date>     <Date>
#  1:     1      1 2015-01-09 2015-04-13
#  2:     2      3 2015-04-14 2015-05-04
#  3:     3      1 2015-05-05 2015-06-18
#  4:     4      3 2015-06-19 2015-08-27
#  5:     5      1 2015-08-28 2015-10-29
#  6:     6      3 2015-10-30 2015-11-19
#  7:     7      1 2015-11-20 2016-02-29
#  8:     8      3 2016-03-01 2016-03-21
#  9:     9      1 2016-03-22 2016-05-23
# 10:    10      3 2016-05-24 2016-06-09
# 11:    11      1 2016-06-10 2016-08-02
# 12:    12      3 2016-08-03 2017-07-18
# 13:    13      1 2017-07-19 2017-07-24
# 14:    14      3 2017-08-18 2018-01-23
# 15:    15      2 2018-01-24 2018-01-31
# 16:    16      3 2018-02-01 2018-04-25
# 17:    17      2 2018-04-26 2018-05-06
# 18:    18      3 2018-05-07 2018-07-29
# 19:    19      2 2018-07-30 2018-08-08
# 20:    20      3 2018-08-09 2019-01-15
# 21:    21      2 2019-01-16 2019-01-30
# 22:    22      3 2019-01-31 2019-02-21
# 23:    23      1 2019-02-22 2019-03-21
# 24:    24      3 2019-03-22 2019-04-24
# 25:    25      2 2019-04-25 2019-05-15
# 26:    26      3 2019-05-16 2019-09-13
# 27:    27      1 2019-09-14 2019-10-13
# 28:    28      3 2019-11-04 2020-01-26
# 29:    29      2 2020-01-27 2020-02-05
# 30:    30      3 2020-02-06 2020-04-29
# 31:    31      2 2020-04-30 2020-05-27
# 32:    32      3 2020-05-28 2020-08-19
# 33:    33      2 2020-08-20 2020-08-24
# 34:    34      3 2020-08-25 2020-11-16
# 35:    35      2 2020-11-17 2020-12-13
# 36:    36      3 2020-12-14 2020-12-23
# 37:    37      1 2020-12-24 2021-03-07
#         r   type   start_dt     end_dt
```

It drops the `id` field, I don't know how to map it well back to your original data.

Answer (score 1):

@r2evans solution is more complete, but if you want to explore the use of`foverlaps` you can start with something like this:

```
#split into two frames
data = split(data,by="type")

# key the second frame
setkey(data[[2]], start_dt, end_dt)

# create the rows that have overlaps
overlap = foverlaps(data[[1]],data[[2]], type="any", nomatch=0)

# get the overlapping time periods
overlap[, .(start_dt = max(start_dt,i.start_dt), end_dt=min(end_dt,i.end_dt)), by=1:nrow(overlap)][,type:=3]
```

Output:

```
   nrow   start_dt     end_dt type
 1:    1 2015-04-14 2015-05-04    3
 2:    2 2015-06-19 2015-08-27    3
 3:    3 2015-10-30 2015-11-19    3
 4:    4 2016-03-01 2016-03-21    3
 5:    5 2016-05-24 2016-06-09    3
 6:    6 2016-08-03 2017-07-18    3
 7:    7 2017-08-18 2018-01-23    3
 8:    8 2018-02-01 2018-04-25    3
 9:    9 2018-05-07 2018-07-29    3
10:   10 2018-08-09 2019-01-15    3
11:   11 2019-01-31 2019-02-21    3
12:   12 2019-03-22 2019-04-24    3
13:   13 2019-05-16 2019-09-13    3
14:   14 2019-11-04 2020-01-26    3
15:   15 2020-02-06 2020-04-29    3
16:   16 2020-05-28 2020-08-19    3
17:   17 2020-08-25 2020-11-16    3
18:   18 2020-12-14 2020-12-23    3
```

The sum of those overlap days is 1492.